# Enumerate setcounter

Tags: enumerate, counters

I want my list to look like:
1.
2.
3-6.
7.

I tried:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \item 
    \item[3-6] 
    \setcounter{enumerate}{7}
    \item
\end{enumerate}
```

Which result in an error. How can I change the enumerate counter to achieve the desired result?

Comment: HAve you tried with `\setcounter{enumi}{0}`?

Comment: Wow I am so stupid. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counter(s) are called `enumi` (...`ii`, `iii` depending on nesting), and are incremented before the `\item`. So:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \item 
    \item[3-6] 
    \setcounter{enumi}{6}
    \item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]